# How to use expand in snakemake when some particular combinations of wildcards are not desired?

Tags: python, wildcard, python-itertools, higher-order-functions, snakemake

Let's suppose that I have the following files, on which I want to apply some processing automatically using snakemake:

```
test_input_C_1.txt
test_input_B_2.txt
test_input_A_2.txt
test_input_A_1.txt
```

The following snakefile uses `expand` to determine all the potential final results file:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("test_output_{text}_{num}.txt", text=["A", "B", "C"], num=[1, 2])

rule make_output:
    input: "test_input_{text}_{num}.txt"
    output: "test_output_{text}_{num}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        md5sum {input} > {output}
        """
```

Executing the above snakefile results in the following error:

```
MissingInputException in line 4 of /tmp/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule make_output:
test_input_B_1.txt
```

The reason for that error is that `expand` uses `itertools.product` under the hood to generate the wildcards combinations, some of which happen to correspond to missing files.

**How to filter out the undesired wildcards combinations?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `expand` function accepts a second optional non-keyword argument to use a different function from the default one to combine wildcard values.

One can create a filtered version of `itertools.product` by wrapping it in a higher-order generator that checks that the yielded combination of wildcards is not among a pre-established blacklist:

```
from itertools import product

def filter_combinator(combinator, blacklist):
    def filtered_combinator(*args, **kwargs):
        for wc_comb in combinator(*args, **kwargs):
            # Use frozenset instead of tuple
            # in order to accomodate
            # unpredictable wildcard order
            if frozenset(wc_comb) not in blacklist:
                yield wc_comb
    return filtered_combinator

# "B_1" and "C_2" are undesired
forbidden = {
    frozenset({("text", "B"), ("num", 1)}),
    frozenset({("text", "C"), ("num", 2)})}

filtered_product = filter_combinator(product, forbidden)

rule all:
    input:
        # Override default combination generator
        expand("test_output_{text}_{num}.txt", filtered_product, text=["A", "B", "C"], num=[1, 2])

rule make_output:
    input: "test_input_{text}_{num}.txt"
    output: "test_output_{text}_{num}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        md5sum {input} > {output}
        """
```

---

The missing wildcards combinations can be read from the configfile.

Here is an example in json format:

```
{
    "missing" :
    [
        {
            "text" : "B",
            "num" : 1
        },
        {
            "text" : "C",
            "num" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

The `forbidden` set would be read as follows in the snakefile:

```
forbidden = {frozenset(wc_comb.items()) for wc_comb in config["missing"]}
```