# Using multiple filenames as wildcards in Snakemake

Tags: input, wildcard, snakemake

I am trying to create a rule to implement `bedtools` in `snakemake`, which will `closest` a file with bunch of files in another directory.

What I have is, under `/home/bedfiles` directory, 20 bed files:

```
1A.bed , 2B_83.bed , 3f_33.bed ...
```

What I want is, under `/home/bedfiles` directory, 20 modified bed files:

```
1A_modified,  2B_83_modified , 3f_33_modified ...
```

So the bash command would be :

```
filelist='/home/bedfiles/*.bed'
for mfile in $filelist;
do
bedtools closest -a /home/other/merged.txt -b ${mfile} > ${mfile}_modified
```

So this command would make files with `_modified` extension, in `/home/bedfiles` directory.

I want to implement this with `Snakemake`, however I keep having a syntax error, that I have no idea of how to fix. My trial is:

**Step1:Getting the first part of bed files in the directory**

```
FIRSTPART = [f.split(".")[0] for f in os.listdir("/home/bedfiles") if f.endswith('.bed')]
```

**Step2: Defining the output name and folder**

```
MODIFIED = expand("/home/bedfiles/{first}_modified", first=FIRSTPART)
```

**Step3: Writing this in `rule all`:**

```
rule all:
   input: MODIFIED
```

**Step4: Making a specific rule to implement 'bedtools closest'**

```
rule closest:

    input:
        input1 = "/home/other/merged.txt" , \
        input2 = expand("/home/bedfiles/{first}.bed", first=FIRSTPART) 

    output:
        expand("/home/bedfiles/{first}_modified", first=FIRSTPART)  

    shell:
        """ bedtools closest -a {input.input1} -b {input.input2} > {output} """
```

And it throws me the error at the line for rule all,input:

```
invalid syntax
```

Do you know how to overpass this error or any other way to implement it?

PS : Writing the names of the files one by one is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the call to `expand` in your definition of `input` and `output` in `closest`. You're currently passing in a vector of 20 filenames as `input.input2` and a vector of 20 filenames as `output`.

That is, your rule `closest` is currently trying to run once and create 20 files; whereas it should run 20 times and create a single file each time.

In `closest` you want `input.input2` to be a single file and `output` to be a single file each time that rule is ran:

```
FIRSTPART = [f.split(".")[0] for f in os.listdir("/home/bedfiles") if f.endswith('.bed')]

print("These are the input files:")
print([f + ".bed" for f in FIRSTPART])

MODIFIED = expand("/home/bedfiles/{first}_modified", first=FIRSTPART)
print("These will be created")
print(MODIFIED)

rule all:
   input: MODIFIED

rule closest:
    message: """
        Converts /home/other/merged.txt and /some/dir/xyz.bed
        into /some/dir/xyz_modified
        """

    input:
        input1 = "/home/other/merged.txt",
        input2 = "{prefix}.bed" 

    output:    "{prefix}_modified"  

    shell:
        """ 
        bedtools closest -a {input.input1} -b {input.input2} > {output}
        """
```

---

Here's an experiment:

Move yourself into a temporary directory and within that directory do the following:

```
mkdir bedfiles                                                                  
touch bedfiles/{a,b,c,d}.bed
```

Then add a file called `Snakefile` into your current directory that contains the following code

```
import os                                                                         
import os.path
import re

input_dir = "bedfiles"
input_files = [os.path.join(input_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(input_dir)]

print(input_files)                                                                

output_files = [re.sub(".bed$", "_modified", f) for f in input_files]             

print(output_files)                                                               

rule all:                                                                         
    input: output_files                                                           

rule mover:                                                                       
    input: "{prefix}.bed"                                                         
    output: "{prefix}_modified"                                                   
    shell:                                                                        
       """ cp {input} {output} """
```

Then run it using `snakemake` at the command line. Snakemake is goal-oriented; it works out how to make your desired outputs based on the existing files.

Comment: But then, if I dont expand, how can I specify the output name in rule all?

Comment: Also, when I say /path/to/bedfiles/{prefix}.bed, where do I specify this prefix? Is it saying *.bed as in bash?

Comment: I didn't say to modify `rule all`, keep the expansion there. The `prefix` is automatically defined becuase the input `.bed` and the output `_modified` file are going in the same directory. Snakemake will look at the filenames in `all::input` and, for each one, determine how to make that given the existing files and the defined rules. For example, it will work out that "/home/bedfiles/1A_modified" can be made from "/home/bedfiles/1A.bed" using rule `closest` by automatically setting `prefix` to "/home/bedfiles/1A".

Comment: So should I also remove FIRSTPART variable?

Comment: is it possible to edit your answer to show of the parts? Because if I remove FIRSTPART which keeps the filenames, then how can I expand? Also, if I say only {prefix} without saying anything else, how can I know that it does not find another bed file in another directory?

Comment: Don't remove FIRSTPART, it defines the input files, and from it you construct the targets of your workflow.

Comment: but then again, how can I know that {prefix} is /home/bedfiles and not /home/other/other/otherfiles if they have both .bed files inside?

Comment: The workflow will only generate those files that are specified as the input to the first rule in your Snakefile, so it will only generate those files in your `all::input` and these all have the form `/home/bedfiles/<some_sample>_modified` by construction

Comment: Thank you for extending your reply. I was missing the declaration for input_files, therefore I couldnt grap the right bed files. That is an excellent answer! Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: In here, if I would not create the _modified files, so it wouldnt grab it from the rule all, how would I specify the input file ? would it be rule something : input : input_files or input: for f in input_files ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy one: invalid syntax refers to a missing `,` after `input1 = "/home/other/merged.txt"`
Hope it helps
Marc

Comment: @bapors I think snakemake sometimes throws errors reporting the line where the rule starts. But maybe not for syntax errors...

Comment: I dont' think this deserved to be downvoted, there was a genuine syntax error in the original posting