# Snakemake: Error with unexisting wildcard

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

> Edit 2 : I figure it out. I posted my answer as reply.
>
> Edit 1 : I added a beginning of solution at the end of the question following @bli advices and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185568/1025741

I'm writing a snakemake file where I parse a samplesheet file (defined in the yaml configuration file) in order to concatenate files listed in this samplesheet.

Samplesheet looks like:

```
sample  unit    fq1 fq2
A   lane1   A.l1.1.R1.txt   A.l1.1.R2.txt
A   lane1   A.l1.2.R1.txt   A.l1.2.R2.txt
A   lane2   A.l2.R1.txt A.l2.R2.txt
B   lane1   B.l1.R1.txt B.l1.R2.txt
```

The idea is to concatenate files (listed in fq1 and fq2) from the same sample and sample unit. In this case:

- `A.l1.1.R1.txt` and `A.l2.2.R1.txt` will be concatenated
- `A.l1.1.R2.txt` and `A.l2.2.R2.txt` will be concatenated

The other files will not be concatenated but will also be reported in this directory structure:

```
{sample}/
    {sample}_{unit}_merged_R1.txt
    {sample}_{unit}_merged_R2.txt
```

So at the end for this example I should have:

```
A/
  A_lane1_merged_R1.txt
  A_lane1_merged_R2.txt
  A_lane2_merged_R1.txt
  A_lane2_merged_R2.txt
B/
  B_lane1_merged_R1.txt
  B_lane1_merged_R2.txt
```

Here's my snakemake file to execute such task:

```
import pandas as pd
shell.executable("bash")

configfile: "config.yaml"

# open samplesheet
units = pd.read_table(config["units"], dtype=str)
units = units.set_index(["sample", "unit"])


rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique(),
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique()),
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt",
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique(),
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique())


def get_fastq_r1(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq1"]].dropna().values.flatten()

def get_fastq_r2(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq2"]].dropna().values.flatten()


rule merge:
    input:
        r1 = get_fastq_r1,
        r2 = get_fastq_r2
    output:
        "{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
        "{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo {input.r1} > {sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt
        echo {input.r2} > {sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt
        """
```

and the config.yaml :

```
units: units.tsv
```

But I have an error as I don't have a sample `B` with unit = `lane2`:

```
InputFunctionException in line 29 of /home/nrosewick/Documents/analysis/pilot_data_ADX17009/workflow/test_snakemake/Snakefile:
KeyError: ('B', 'lane2')
Wildcards:
sample=B
unit=lane2
```

Is there a way/trick to avoid this kind of error ?
Thanks

> Beginning of solution

Following @bli advice I used a filtered version of itertools.product by wrapping it in a higher-order generator that checks that the yielded combination of wildcards is among a pre-established list:

```
import pandas as pd
shell.executable("bash")

configfile: "config.yaml"

### 
from itertools import product

def filter_combinator(combinator, inlist):
    def filtered_combinator(*args, **kwargs):
        for wc_comb in combinator(*args, **kwargs):
            # Use frozenset instead of tuple
            # in order to accomodate
            # unpredictable wildcard order
            if frozenset(wc_comb) in inlist:
                yield wc_comb
    return filtered_combinator

# open samplesheet
units = pd.read_table(config["units"], dtype=str)

# list of pair sample-unit included in the samplesheet
inList={
    frozenset({("sample", "A"), ("unit", "lane1")}),
    frozenset({("sample", "A"), ("unit", "lane2")}),
    frozenset({("sample", "B"), ("unit", "lane1")})}

# set df index
units = units.set_index(["sample", "unit"])

# build new iterator
filtered_product = filter_combinator(product, inList)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
            filtered_product,
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique().values,
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique().values),
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt",
            filtered_product,
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique().values,
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique().values)


def get_fastq_r1(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq1"]].dropna().values.flatten()

def get_fastq_r2(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq2"]].dropna().values.flatten()

rule merge:
    input:
        r1 = get_fastq_r1,
        r2 = get_fastq_r2
    output:
        "{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
        "{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt"
    message:
        "test"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input.r1} > {sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt
        cat {input.r2} > {sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt
        """
```

But it returns me an error when running `snakemake -n`:

```
Job 1: test

RuleException in line 53 of /home/nrosewick/Documents/analysis/pilot_data_ADX17009/workflow/test_snakemake/Snakefile:
NameError: The name 'sample' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185568/1878788

Comment: I added a solution based on your advice but I've an other error now ...

Comment: I solved it myself. I had an error in the ouput of the merge rule. I will post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I found based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185568/1025741 :

```
import pandas as pd
shell.executable("bash")

configfile: "config.yaml"

### 
from itertools import product

def filter_combinator(combinator, inlist):
    def filtered_combinator(*args, **kwargs):
        for wc_comb in combinator(*args, **kwargs):
            # Use frozenset instead of tuple
            # in order to accomodate
            # unpredictable wildcard order
            if frozenset(wc_comb) in inlist:
                yield wc_comb
    return filtered_combinator

# open samplesheet
units = pd.read_table(config["units"], dtype=str)

# list of pair sample-unit
#inList=units[["sample","unit"]].drop_duplicates().to_dict('r')
inList={
    frozenset({("sample", "A"), ("unit", "lane1")}),
    frozenset({("sample", "A"), ("unit", "lane2")}),
    frozenset({("sample", "B"), ("unit", "lane1")})}

# set df index
units=units.set_index(["sample","unit"])

# build new iterator
filtered_product = filter_combinator(product, inList)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
            filtered_product,
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique().values,
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique().values),
        expand("{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt",
            filtered_product,
            sample=units.index.get_level_values('sample').unique().values,
            unit=units.index.get_level_values('unit').unique().values)


def get_fastq_r1(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq1"]].dropna().values.flatten()

def get_fastq_r2(wildcards):
    return units.loc[(wildcards.sample, wildcards.unit), ["fq2"]].dropna().values.flatten()

rule merge:
    input:
        r1=get_fastq_r1,
        r2=get_fastq_r2
    output:
        r1_o="{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R1.txt",
        r2_o="{sample}/{sample}_{unit}_merge_R2.txt"
    message:
        "test"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input.r1} > {output.r1_o}
        cat {input.r2} > {output.r2_o}
        """
```